# How to generate Image map cords

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, imagemap

My current layout uses Image Mapping to do function such as onclick and onrollover.

I want to create a backend system that will allow staff to add new areas to the map/image but I would require them to click a mapped image (the same as the layout/themes) in order to accurately create the rollover and onclick.

My idea is to add all co-ords into mysql and then using PHP to show all co-ords within a table.

Therefore when a member of staff creates a new co-ordinate we insert the co-ordinates they have clicked on the image into the table which will then update on site refresh.

I just need to know how I might go about doing the mapping

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm a little confused, could you show an example? Are you talking about an HTML image map (gosh I haven't even thought about those in YEARS) or something else?

Comment: I can`t find what exactly the problem is. I don`t think that this can be done without JavaScript. I suppose you can use something like this tool - http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap . First you generate the the points and then store them in the database. If this is the idea of the question :)

Comment: Basically what I want to do is allow logged in members of staff to be able to click an image within the backend panel that will resemble that of the current layout.. Once clicked the co-ordinates within the image they have clicked will be saved or used to create a new onrollover/onclick area. I am fine with using Javascript/Jquery/Ajax etc..

Comment: I mean if you click on the image (THE IMAGE ONLY) then (BOOOOM!) Co-ordinates save, allowing that member of staff to insert a new onrollover/onclick option(BACKEND). The reason this image will be backend is because I want staff to be able to use the map (like a normal user) without development options appearing.